# Whats wrong with this php code that exports mysql records to csv?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have this bit of code on my file and its working well for a different file but on this new file which does the same thing with the one that works, it doesn't work

```
mysql_select_db($db);
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT 
    CONCAT(`employees`.`first_name`,
            ' ',
            `employees`.`middle_name`,
            ' ',
            `employees`.`last_name`) AS `fullname`,
    `banks`.`bank_code`,
    `bank_branch_code`.`branch_code`,
    `employees`.`account_number`,
    `pay_roll_history`.`payable`,
    `employees`.`email`,
    `banks`.`payment_type`,
    `banks`.`process_mode`
FROM
    `employees`,
    `banks`,
    `bank_branch_code`,
    `pay_roll_history`
WHERE
    `employees`.`bank_id` = `banks`.`bank_id` 
    AND `employees`.`employee_id` = `pay_roll_history`.`employee_id` 
    AND `banks`.`bank_id` = `bank_branch_code`.`bank_id` 
    AND `pay_roll_history`.`payroll_date` = '$this_date'
");

//Open a csv file
$fp = fopen('c:\users\oteheddy\Desktop\test\BankReport.csv', 'w');


//*************************************
// fetch a row and write the column names out to the file
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$line = "";
$comma = "";

foreach($row as $name => $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);

// remove the result pointer back to the start
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
```

and i get these error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pitss\export\bankexport.php on line 32
>
> Warning: mysql_data_seek() [function.mysql-data-seek]: Offset 0 is invalid for MySQL result index 18 (or the query data is unbuffered) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pitss\export\bankexport.php on line 40

What i'm i doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not using [PHP's built in CSV functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: What's in $row after the mysql_fetch_assoc($result)?  Does $result actually contain any values?  And you should also use the CSV functions . . .I'm guessing $result is empty, as that would also explain why the mysql_data_seek() fails

Comment: **PLEASE TELL ME YOU DON'T _REALLY_ WORK FOR A BANK!**

Comment: $result is not empty cause i ran it against mysql and it pulls records. This same code works for another file.

Answer (score 1):

1st thing is 1st:
Make sure the query does **not** have an error, you can use `mysql_error()` in your case.

---

2nd thing:
 [**Use prepared queries**](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html), the one you have now can lead to a [bobby-table](http://bobby-tables.com/)...

Answer (score 0):

This error raises if your $row variable is not an array.

So the query itself might raised an error.

Try to check the mysql errors with `mysql_error()` and do proper error handling everywhere else too.

Answer (score 0):

you don't check if `$result` is a resource or just `FALSE`,
you don't check that you got an array in `$row`, could be `FALSE`

you can use mysql_error() to see the last database error